# Mounting a file share on CF

Tags: cloud-foundry

My application hosted on CF (PCFDev locally) needs to access network file shares. I searched for a way to mount a file share to PCFDev and didn't find anything that looks like a solutions.

I came across this but it is experimental/obsolete https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/services/volume-services.html

My question is: Is there a way to mount a network file share so that my application hosted on CF would have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Volume services are still experimental in Cloud Foundry, and so aren't in PCFDev yet.

You can check the latest version of the docs here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/volume-services-v2.10.html

Additionally the [Cloud Foundry Slack](http://slack.cloudfoundry.org)'s Persi channel is a good place to ask questions about Volume Services.